# need an example using adoconection to avoid mysql server has gone away

Tags: mysql, delphi, ado

i have a Desktop application that use remote database unfortunately i can't change the memory limit there, my application was Ok when i use local database or LAN database. but when using a remote database i often found error "mysql server has gone away' my assumption is i not using adoconnection well. i do the ado.committrans and ado.begintrans but i didnt do the ado.close or ado.free . . i need an example of this... what function of ado i use and where i do put them ? each transaction including showing to dbgrid ? or something....
my hosting config is :

> ```
> > safe mode = Off (tidak dapat diubah)
>
> memory_limit = 256M (MAXIMUM)
>
> max_execution_time = 30 (MAXIMUM in seconds)
>
> max_input_time = 60 (MAXIMUM in seconds)
>
> post_max_size = 64M (MAXIMUM)
>
> upload_max_filesize = 64M (MAXIMUM)
>
> enable_dl = Off (tidak dapat diubah)
>
> Stimultan connection: 25 connections/koneksi
>
> **Time out without activity: 60 sec**
> ```

**i wonder if in my proj. i didn't keep my connection active**

here my code:

```
Procedure TForm1.show;
Begin
with query do begin
sql.clear;//menghapus query yang masih ada jika ada
sql.Text:='select * from daftar where tanggal = curdate() order by id asc';
open;//membuka query
end;
end;
  function AddLeadingZeroes(const aNumber, Length : integer) : string;
begin
   result := SysUtils.Format('%.*d', [Length, aNumber]) ;
end;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
a:string;
begin
a:=AddLeadingZeroes(strtoint(edit3.Text),4);
 edit3.text:=a;
 edit2.text:=AnsiUpperCase(edit2.text);
if (edit2.text='') or (edit3.text='')
  then
    begin
      showmessage('Nomor Medrek HARUS diisi terlebih dahulu');
      edit2.setfocus
    end
  else
    begin
      con.BeginTrans;
      query1.SQL.Clear;
      query1.SQL.text :='Select Nama from medrek where LETTER='+QuotedStr(edit2.text)+'AND ID='+QuotedStr(edit3.text)+';';
      Screen.Cursor:=crHourGlass;
      query1.open;
      If query1.RECORDCOUNT = 0
        Then
          begin
            ShowMessage('NOMOR MEDREK BELUM TERDAFTAR') ;
            edit1.Color := clMaroon;
            edit1.clear ;
            con.CommitTrans;
          end
        ELSE
          begin
            edit1.text := query1.FieldByName('Nama').AsString;
            edit1.Color := clYellow;
            query.Requery();
            con.CommitTrans;
          END;
    query1.close;
    Screen.Cursor:=crDefault;

    end

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

if (edit1.text='') or (combobox1.text='') or (combobox2.text='') or (combobox3.text='')  or (combobox4.text='') then
    begin
    MessageDlg('DATA BELUM LENGKAP !',mtError, mbOKCancel, 0);
    end
      else
        begin
        Screen.Cursor:=crHourGlass;
            con.BeginTrans;
            with query do
            begin
                sql.Clear;
                SQL.Text:='INSERT INTO daftar (tanggal,NO_MEDREC, NAMA, lAMA, STATUS, KETERANGAN, POLI) VALUES ("'+formatdatetime('yyyy-mm-dd',today())+'","'+concat(Edit2.Text,'-',edit3.text)+'","'+Edit1.Text+'","'+combobox1.text+'","'+combobox3.text+'","'+combobox2.text+'","'+combobox4.text+'")';
                execsql;//untuk mengeksekusi perintah SQL
                Showmessage('Data berhasil disimpan');
                show;
            end;
        con.CommitTrans;
        Screen.Cursor:=crDefault;
        button1.Enabled:=false;
        button2.Enabled:=false;
          query1.close;
        end;
end;
procedure TForm1.ComboBox3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
IF combobox3.text='UMUM'  THEN
  begin
   EDIT5.Color:=clBlack;
   EDIT5.CLEAR;
   EDIT5.ReadOnly := true
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
   EDIT5.Color:=clWHITE   ;
   EDIT5.ReadOnly := FALSE
   END

END;
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
con.connected:=true;
 with query do
            begin
                sql.Clear;
                SQL.Text:='Select * from daftar where tanggal = curdate()';
                execsql;//untuk mengeksekusi perintah SQL

                show;
                end;

button1.Enabled:=TRUE;
button2.Enabled:=TRUE;
edit1.Clear;
edit2.Clear;
edit3.Clear;
edit5.Clear;
combobox1.ClearSelection;
combobox2.ClearSelection;
Combobox3.ClearSelection;
combobox4.ClearSelection;
edit2.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
con.connected:=true;
 with query do
            begin
                sql.Clear;
                SQL.Text:='Select * from daftar where tanggal = curdate()';
                execsql;//untuk mengeksekusi perintah SQL

                show;
                end;
Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.P2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
FORM2.SHOWMODAL
end;

procedure TForm1.P1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
form3.showmodal;
end;





procedure TForm1.CETAKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  form4.show;
end;

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
if DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo mod 2 =0 then
DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clskyBlue; //pilih warnanya
DBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(rect, datacol, column, state);



if DataSource1.DataSet.RecNo > 0 then
begin
if Column.Title.Caption = 'No.' then
DBGrid1.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top, IntToStr(DataSource1.DataSet.RecNo));
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CARIHISTORYPASIEN1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
form5.show;
end;

End.
```

i set ado properties directly to its properties. not using code,,,,
provider for adoconnection. Provider=MSDASQL.1
and checked = true on adoconnection.connected

thank you..

Comment: create a timer that fires every `n` seconds. At which point send `select 1` from the server.

Comment: Which driver are you using so as to be able to connect to a MySql server using Ado?  Odbc?

Comment: i am using odbc 3.51 because common pc in my office are dual core 32 bit... with 1gb ram using xp or seven..

Comment: Afaik, an ADO connection over the internet is stateful (or at least the objects in the local  ADO objects are), so from first principles, I'd expect that dropping the connection in between transactions would be less prone to error than keeping it open.  Not that I've ever connected to a MySql server over the i'net via ADO, mind you.

Answer (score 0):

> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is
>   that the server timed out and closed the connection. In this case, you
>   normally get one of the following error codes (which one you get is
>   operating system-dependent).

I received this error due to this

> You have encountered a timeout on the server side and the automatic
>   reconnection in the client is disabled (the reconnect flag in the
>   MYSQL structure is equal to 0).

But complete reasons for this error is described in below link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Naruto it's probably a time out. I have my own function that executes the SQL in a ADOQuery and reconnect to the database if it fails.

If it fails more than three times it raise an exception with message and the query I tried to execute.

Parameter `Ex` sets the execution to Open or ExecSQL.

Call the function with your ADOQuery and true if you want to ExecSQL or false if you want to open the query.

```
function ExecuteMySQL(var Q: TADOQuery; Ex:boolean):integer;
const
     MaxNoOfTry : integer = 3;
var
     NoOfTry : integer;
     msg     : string;

begin
  Result:= 0;
  NoOfTry := 0;
  while (NoOfTry < MaxNoOfTry) do
  begin
    inc(NoOfTry);
    try
      if Ex then
        Result := Q.ExecSQL
      else
      begin
        msg := Q.SQL.Text;
        Q.Open;
        Result := Q.RecordCount;
      end;
      NoOfTry := MaxNoOfTry+1;
    except
      on E : Exception do
      begin
        Result := -1;
        Msg := E.Message;
        Q.Connection.Close;
        Q.Connection.Open;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  if Result = -1 then
    ShowMessage(Msg+chr(13)+chr(13)+Q.SQL.Text);
end;
```